# How to password protect senstitive content in Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, encryption, passwords

I have a table with sensitive content in Google Sheets. I share the sheet with a couple of colleagues but we also share the same account.

I would like to protect the table cells with a password I set up, so whenever someone tries to edit the cell a pop-up message comes, asking to insert said password.

There is no predefinite function in Google Sheets that allows me to do that so I need to write it myself.

Where do I start with this? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to write an extension, but I'm not entirely sure. That could be a decent starting place.

Comment: Does this help? [Protected Sheets](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en)

Comment: @Steezy unfortunately not, since we share the same account